# Downgrade from elasticsearch 5.1.1 to elasticsearch 2.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I want to downgrade my `elasticsearch` from version 5.1.1 to 2.4.1. Is this possible?

Comment: Try download 2.4.1 and copy the data directory in your machine from 5.1 to 2.4 elasticsearch